# Set the Java source/target value of an Android project in Netbeans?

Tags: android, netbeans

Well, I have a pretty simple problem. I have currently installed the *NBAndroid* Plugin for *Netbeans*.
Everything works fine. If there wasn't the fact that I can't use Lambdas and Co (**Version 1.5**). I tried to change this value in the *project properties*, but there is no single possibility to do that; or not?

```
[javac] warning: [options] source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
[javac] warning: [options] target value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
[javac] warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
```

Thank you for your advices!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Locate `ant.properties` in your project tree and add following two lines into it replacing 1.8 with the Java SDK version you have. It should be greater than 1.5 and current release (1.8).

```
java.target=1.8
java.source=1.8
```

Hope it helps.